# C++. I want to save a specific line of characters, that change, in a string

Tags: c++, regex

I run a command in CMD through my C++ app which saves the output from that command. In that output, there is a port number and a remote API token, that changes upon each restart of the application im targeting.

This is the output I'm getting through my CMD command, which I store in a string:

```
"C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/LeagueClientUx.exe" "--riotclient-auth-token=5NFOIOqKB9EfSVsxBMrFUw" "--riotclient-app-port=63498" "--no-rads" "--disable-self-update" "--region=EUW" "--locale=en_GB" "--remoting-auth-token=***vx5yZOk_TkAt9YKq-PEucw***" "--respawn-command=LeagueClient.exe" "--respawn-display-name=League of Legends" "--app-port=63530" "--install-directory=C:\Riot Games\League of Legends" "--app-name=LeagueClient" "--ux-name=LeagueClientUx" "--ux-helper-name=LeagueClientUxHelper" "--log-dir=LeagueClient Logs" "--crash-reporting=crashpad" "--crash-environment=EUW1" "--crash-pipe=\\.\pipe\crashpad_19692_AJMBMQYOZVYYJMRF" "--app-log-file-path=C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/Logs/LeagueClient Logs/2020-07-09T12-55-09_19692_LeagueClient.log" "--app-pid=19692" "--output-base-dir=C:\Riot Games\League of Legends" "--no-proxy-server"
```

I've tried some stuff with the regex library, and managed to split my results up into words, but I still can't figure out how I save a specific line, that is the port number and the result of remoting-auth-token="characters I want to save".

My code to find out how many words are in the output string:

```
std::string output = exec("wmic PROCESS WHERE name='LeagueClientUx.exe' GET commandline");

std::regex wregex("(\\w+)");
auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(output.begin(), output.end(), wregex);
auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();
std::cout << "Found: " << std::distance(words_begin, words_end) << std::endl;

PrintMatch(words_begin, words_end);
```

Output:

´´

Found: 110 CommandLine, C, Riot, Games, League, of, Legends, LeagueClientUx, exe, riotclient, auth, token, 5NFOIOqKB9EfSVsxBMrFUw, riotclient, app, port, 63498, no, rads, disable, self, update, region, EUW, locale, en_GB, remoting, auth, token, vx5yZOk_TkAt9YKq, PEucw, respawn, command, LeagueClient, exe, respawn, display, name, League, of, Legends, app, port, 63530, ´´ And a bit more but character restriction limits me, however the output which I need to store is there. I've set commas to mark new lines in the output.

‘’

Comment: Please show the desired output for this input example.

Comment: Please edit the question to add this information. Don't add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "save". Save to file or just assign to a variable? My guess is that you are confused about how iterators work and are wondering how you can fetch the remote-auth-token and the port number to from the words_begin variable. If the number of "words" in the cmd output is always the same you can use:

```
std::advance(words_begin,16);
std::string port = words_begin->str();
std::advance(words_begin,13);
std::string authToken = words_begin->str();
```

now, normally you would write the regex so as to only match the part you are interested in. Currently, since you are matching every "word", you are dependent on what position the remote auth token and port number are in the cmd output which might cause your application to break if that output ever changes order or add another word in front.

Comment: Thank you for your input, that does the trick almost! However it is not always certain that it will be 110 words - is there a way I can find it when the word count changes ? :s